# simple database solution (local storage) from bash

Tags: database, bash

I am searching for an simple data storage solution, interfaced from local bash (write and read).

Background: I'm collecting sensor data and save values with timestamp (actually in a text file, every week a new file is created).
I like to visualize the data on request with the help of php. 
Is there a database (like sqlite) which can be easily written from bash ?

Comment: There's a command-line interface for mysql.

Comment: i never used databases, so i do not know if it make sense for that purpose.  I have a 2bytes sensor data every minute to write.  so i hope there is a benefit when i read data ... with may file textfile solutions it's not very nice if there are request about more than one week

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [rrdtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/index.en.html). It's a round robin time series db, perfect for visualizations.

Answer (score 2):

`sqlite3` can take a [query as argument](https://sqlite.org/cli.html) (see "Using sqlite3 in a shell script").

```
DB='example'
VAR='sensordata'
QUERY="INSERT INTO table(column) VALUES ('${VAR}')"
sqlite3 "$DB" "$QUERY"
```

What you won't get is string escaping so you need to be sure that `$VAR` is safe from SQL injections.